# Shopify Image slider duplicating images

Tags: shopify

I'm currently new to shopify and using a free theme call saleshunter.
On the product page itself, the thumbnail images on the slider are duplicating. Can you help me solve this?
Here's the code I found for the product images.

```html
<div class="{{ product_image_width }}">
    <div class="product-single__images">
     <div class="product-single__photos slick-slider manual-init" id="ProductPhoto">
      {% for image in product.images %}
       <div class="product-single__photos__item">
        {% assign featured_image = current_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}
        <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: product_image_size }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
       </div>
      {% endfor %}
     </div>

     {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
      <div class="product-single__thumbnails slick-slider manual-init" id="ProductThumbs">
       {% for image in product.images %}
        {% for variant in image.variants %}
         <div class="product-single__thumbnails__item" {% if image.attached_to_variant? %} data-variant="{{ variant.id }}" {% endif %}
           data-index="{{ image.position }}">
          <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: product_thumb_size }}"
            alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
         </div>
        {% else %}
         <div class="product-single__thumbnails__item">
          <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: product_thumb_size }}"
            alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
         </div>
        {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %}

      </div>
     {% endif %}
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the image thumbnails duplicate based on the variants you have (i.e. small, medium, large for a red shirt, blue shirt, and black shirt). Meaning you will have 3 duplicates of one color shirt. To prevent this from happening, remove this code:

```
{% for variant in image.variants %}
      <div class="product-single__thumbnails__item" {% if image.attached_to_variant? %} data-variant="{{ variant.id }}" {% endif %}
                                     data-index="{{ image.position }}">
             <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: product_thumb_size }}"
                         alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
      </div>
{% else %}
```

as well as one of the {% endfor %} after this code:

```
<div class="product-single__thumbnails__item">
        <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: product_thumb_size }}"
                 alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
</div>
```